Why 'we're seeing' is used not 'we see' in '...So we're certainly seeing, by some accounts, up to almost 100 pounds...'?
From New Yorkers urged to break down cardboard boxes 0:42

So we're certainly seeing, by some accounts, up to almost 100 pounds
of cardboard per household per year set out at the curb. Joshua
Goodman is the Deputy Commissioner of Public Affairs and Customer
Experience at the New York City Department of Sanitation.

LONGMAN and Oxford say that the progressive tense can't be used for see in most situations. Is the present continuous used to express future situations similar to Why "we are seeing them tonight" is correct??

The present continuous "we are seeing" is used to indicate that something is current and ongoing.
While it is true that the simple present "we see" also indicates something presently ongoing, it is used more to indicate something is more fixed such as a general truth like "we see the sun rise every morning".
The present continuous is better for referring to situations that haven't always existed and may change again - they are just current and ongoing. In your example, the speaker is referring to a current trend - the amount of cardboard being disposed of at the curbside. Presumably, the volume hasn't always been that high, and perhaps they hope it will change in the future, so it isn't a fixed situation or a general truth.
